# convex hull for tangent function

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-hulls

I would like to ask if I can obtain a convex hull for the function 
tan(S2-S1) where S1 and S2 are unknown angles while knowing the maximum/minimum limits on (S2-S1).

Comment: What does that mean?

Comment: I mean if I have a segment of a tangent function (which is not convex), can I obtain a convex hull around that segment?